# Is there another way to do this without claiming def to_s

Tags: ruby

```
class BookInStock
  def initialize(isbn,price)
    @isbn = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  end
end

def to_s
  #"ISBN: #{@isbn}, price: #{@price}"
end

b1 = BookInStock.new("isbn1", 3)
puts b1
b2 = BookInStock.new("isbn2", 3.14)
puts b2
b3 = BookInStock.new("isbn3", 5.67)
puts b3
```

Cant instead of doing the `def to_s`, can I do the following?

```
b1 = BookInStock.new("isbn1", 3)
puts "#{isbn}, #{price}"
```

I get blank as a response.

Comment: You *could* do that, I am not sure why you would want to. You just need to reference the object that those attributes are defined on: `puts "#{b1.isbn}, #{b1.price}"`. You may also need to declare `attr_reader :isbn, :price`

Comment: Don't be using Float for monetary values. BigDecimal is want you want

Answer (score 5):

Normally you expose those properties like this:

```
class BookInStock
  attr_reader :isbn
  attr_reader :price
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
puts "#{b1.isbn}, #{b1.price}"
```

Or given how you're using floats:

```
puts "%s %.2f" % [ b1.isbn, b1.price ]
```